# How can I join two commands together in vim?

Tags: vim, plugins, syntax, keymapping

I am trying to combine two commands for Bundle plugin in vim. Because BundleUpdate pulls all plugins and installs them and it is slow. I have the following below. The first two works fine, but the third one does not. It stops after the `BundleClean` operation. How can I make vim to run second command?

```
command! -bang BI BundleInstall<bang>
command! -bang BC BundleClean<bang>
;not working below
command! -bang BU BundleClean<bang> | BundleInstall<bang>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `-bar` as an argument to `:command` in addition to `-bang`, otherwise chaining commands and adding comments is not possible for user-defined commands.

You will have to use

```
command! -bar -bang BU BC<bang> | BI<bang>
```

in place of what you have currently because `Bundle*` commands do not have `-bar` argument.

There is another alternative: use `execute`:

```
command! -bang BU execute 'BundleClean<bang>' | execute 'BundleInstall<bang>'
```

. Beware of using `execute '…<some-arg>'`, it is not going to work properly for some arguments’ values. It works fine for both possible expansions of `<bang>`.

Comment: hi Zyx, isn't it funny?? I just learned that, and here comes a question! Now finally I can upvote your answer to say thank you!! +1

Comment: question to your `BC<bang> | BI<bang>` does it mean if we want to chain some user-defined cmds, which are in some plugin and without `-bar`, we could write wrapper commands for them and with `-bar`, then we could chain the wrapper commands with `|` eventually the plugin defined commands get chained?

Comment: @Kent It is easy to test. Commands are splitted before expansion, not after, thus it works normally.

Comment: @ZyX Your commands did not work for me. I think Kent is right that since the Bundle Plugin commands do not have `-bar` so I have to create a function to execute them in sequence. Could you please confirm if your commands worked for you?

Comment: @Prometheus in fact I just learned this `-bar` stuff from Zyx (a comment to another post) just 5mins b4 you post your question. :)  Did you add `-bar` to your `BC` command definition?

Comment: BU got mapped to `BundleClean` somehow, and I had to restart `vim`. It is working for me. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do `BundleClean | BundleInstall`.

Because `BundleClean` is a user-defined command, it is defined by `Vundle` plugin:

```
 com! -nargs=? -bang   BundleClean call vundle#installer#clean('!' == '<bang>')
```

Note that, there is no `-bar` in this command definition.

If you `:h command-bar` you will see:

```
-bar        The command can be followed by a "|" and another command.
        A "|" inside the command argument is not allowed then.
        Also checks for a " to start a comment.
```

that is, the `BundleClean` cannot be followed by another command by `|`.

You could however write a function, in the function you execute the two commands. And let your `BU` command call your function.